# Set the rendered value to the dropdown using ajax jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

There is no problem in getting the value in textbox for username and email but i am having the problem in getting the rendered value i.e Rolename in the dropdown list.
    //Controller class
    public JsonResult GetByID(int ID)
        {
            var user = userRepo.GetAllUsers().Find(x => x.UserID.Equals(ID));
            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getByID(UserID)
{
    debugger;
    $('.uname').css('border-color', 'green');
    $('.mail').css('border-color', 'green');
    $.ajax({

        url: "../Easyshop/User/GetByID/" + UserID,
        type: "Get",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result)
        {
            debugger;
            $('#Username').val(result.Username);
            $('#Email').val(result.Email);
            $('#roleName').val(result.RoleName);
        },
        error: function (errormessage)
        {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

```
result:Object
ConfirmPassword:null
Email:"bishal@gmail.com"
Password:null
RoleID:0
RoleName:"Member"
UserID:4
Username:"Bishal"
roleList:null
```

Comment: Is error function fired?

Comment: nope error function is not fired coz it works fine for textbox

Comment: do you have values created in de DDL? 
<select id="ddl">
<option value="0">Rol</option>
<option value="1">Admin</option>
<option value="2">User</option>
</select>

Comment: yes .I did render it from the database

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.RoleID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.roleList, new { @class = "form-control", @id="roleName"})

Comment: write `console.log(result)` in success function and let me show what is output

Comment: in the result i get the value of the selected id For eg : if i select id 1 ,i get the username 'anand', email 'hello@domain.com' and roleName 'Admin'

Comment: What value you are binding in DDL?

Comment: i m binding list of the role from the database

Comment: You are binding from database. What value you are setting to DDL. For eg: Id & Name of Roles. Like wise i am asking

Comment: i m setting name of roles

Comment: Could you explain in detail about Model.roleList object value

Comment: If you could show the html result of the DDL it might be easier to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For Single value use below syntax

```html
$("#roleName").empty();
$("#roleName").append('<option value="' + result.RoleName + '">' + "" + '</option>');
```

2. If you have to load list of values

```html
 $("#roleName").empty();

 $("#roleName").append('<option value="' + 0 + '">' +"" + '</option>');

 $.each(data, function (i, RoleName) {

     $("#roleName").append('<option value="' + RoleName.Value + '">' +

     RoleName.Text + '</option>');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much